# ModRewrite weird redirect behavior on removing WWW

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to use some rule on my project to remove `www` from the beginning of the `URL` but I've some problem.

my server structure is:

```
domain.com/beta_folder
domain.com/beta_folder/page+type
domain.com/beta_folder/page+type/content+name
domain.com/beta_folder/page+type/content+name/edit
domain.com/beta_folder/page+type/content+name/etc.

domain.com/beta_folder/.htaccess //here is where my htaccess is
```

`beta_folder` is the site folder, and `content+name` are content vars, created to retrieve pages from the database.

the site works perfect with this rules

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(page\+type/)([a-zA-Z0-9_+-]+)[/]?$ page_folder/page.php?varname=$2
```

My intention was to remove `www`, so I've added this rule but it isn't effective

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(page\+type/)([a-zA-Z0-9_+-]+)[/]?$ page_folder/page.php?varname=$2
```

My problem starts if I digit `www` in front of my domain name:

this works

```
http://domain.com/beta_folder/page+type/content+name
```

if i write

```
http://www.domain.com/beta_folder/page+type/content+name
```

the rewrite rule redirect me at

```
http://www.domain.compage+type/content+name
```

if i remove the `www` rules, the problem still active

unfortunately, I can't make a public test for my domain

basically, if I write

```
 http://www.domain.com/beta_folder
```

the rules sends me to

```
 http://domain.com/
```

the only way I've found to solve the problem is to write the folder where my site is, so:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/beta_folder/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I don't undestand why I should write the folder, because my rewrite cond affects
`http://www.domain.com/folder_name/contents` and not `http://www.domain.com/contents`

why `folder_name` missing from the rewriting?

Comment: First thought is that you have `[R=301,L]` which means a 301 redirect and Last rule, so it won't ever get to your second rule will it? ~ Ah sorry, `www` subdomain¬ lol, gotcha

Answer (score 0):

Try this, subtly different example of your rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Shout out if this doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: I've edited my question with a solution, but I'm not sure it's the best way